# how can I hook an S3 static front-end to an API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, post, amazon-s3, backend

I want to run an S3 static website. Easy enough...

I have built a chatbot using dialog flow which I want to connect to my website.

In the past I have used S3 to host many static websites, but as many of you know...CORS...so now i am seeking a backend.

So in the past I'd build a EC2 (Or wix, which allows a Node backend is pretty cool for this.) But I am having trouble finding a solution where I can pass my API calls outside of the browser.

What is the best way to do this???

I have experience with Lambda, API Gateway - I am guessing that one of these could be my answer. I have written a successful API in API Gateway which gets the correct 200 response and reply message back.

I have done my due diligence and sought out an answer on stack and google, lots of questions about how to use S3 as storage, but not a lot of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Should I ditch Dialog Flow and get on Lex? I have a lot of logic in Dialog Flow so I don't want to switch bot apps. Is there an easy way to hook up a backend for a simple post, then pass the response back to the S3 front end.

thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *"pass my API calls outside of the browser."*  Opinion-based questions are off-topic, so you may also want to consider editing your question to remove concepts like "the best way" and instead see if you can ask for something more specific and less subjective/opinion based, such as "Is there a way to ... while avoiding the problem of ...?"

Comment: I've edited my question. Thanks

Yeah i just need to get around CORS, same way you would on a backend, but don't want to setup a server. AWS has a lot of apps for this, I'm thinking API Gateway is my best option (objectively speaking*). I want a user to be able to interact with my front end (HTML,CSS,JS) and once a post is made in HTTP, have that passed to the API and the response returned, resolve the promise and update the element to show the proper value from the JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As happens eventually, if no one answers, i'll find an answer for my own questions. I've used jQuery before for animations, but using it for AJAX got me around the CORS issue. I'm running it thru API gateway in AWS also

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    let question = "ask the bot a question";

    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://kjnflkjfsdf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        },
        "data": JSON.stringify({
            lang: "en",
            query: question,
            sessionId: "12345",
            timezone: "America/New_York"
        })
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        let botResponse =  response.result.fulfillment.speech;
        console.log(botResponse);
    });

});
```